# Validation Summary in TabControl (Silverlight 4)

Tags: silverlight, validation, mvvm, tabcontrol, validationsummary

everyone. Here is my question. I'm using MVVM pattern in my project and i have a UserControl, which has a TabControl on it. TabItems have validations on them.

Main page looks like this:

```
<UserControl>
    <DataInput:ValidationSummary x:Name="ValidationSummary"/>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <DataInput:ValidationSummary />
        <TabControl x:Name="TabControl">
            <TabItem>
                <MyUserControl1 DataContext="{Binding}" />
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem>
                <MyUserControl2 DataContext="{Binding}" />
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem>
                <MyUserControl2 DataContext="{Binding}" />
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And here is a sample code for TabItems:

```
<UserControl>
   <Grid>
     <Text:ExtendedTextBox Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true}" />
     <Data:DataGrid SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedValue, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true}"/>
   </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Target for ValidationSummary is set to LayoutRoot. But actually, it's showing only errors for visible(currently opened) TabItem. And i need to show all the errors from all tabs. How can i achieve this?

Comment: You don't need `DataContext="{Binding}"` in your UserControl's.  Using the parent's DataContext is the default behavior.

Answer (score 4):

Walkor, see this: [Using BindingValidationError to Add Messages to a Validation Summary in Silverlight](http://blog.falafel.com/using-bindingvalidationerror-to-add-messages-to-a-validation-summary-in-silverlight/)

Hope helps!

Comment: Though, it's not an elegant solution, it may be useful, thanks.