# Silverlight 4 ValidationSummary not showing error of non-visible control

Tags: silverlight-4.0, validationsummary

the screen has a tabControl, so many controls are hidden/now-showing until you open that tabItem.
when performing validation, some of these non-visible controls are invalid, but the ValidationSummary is not showing them, not until i open a tabItem that contains those controls with invalid data.

how to make the validationSummary show all errors?

I found similar thread, but the proposed answer doesn't work at all.
[Validation Summary in TabControl (Silverlight 4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403491/validation-summary-in-tabcontrol-silverlight-4)